# Why is ruby -v still showing version 2.0.0 even after successfully installing ruby 2.5.3?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I'm following this tutorial: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/macos/#homebrew

I've successfully installed ruby 2.5.3, however, when I run "ruby -v" on the command line in Terminal, it still says ruby 2.0.0.

My friend told me something about local vs universal installation of ruby and how that can create a conflict, but I'm completely new to this so I'm having trouble understanding how to update the 2.0.0 to 2.5.3 (which I've successfully installed on my machine).

[image]

Comment: why are you using homebrew to install ruby? why not use RVM ruby version manager?  This will allow multiple versions and you can set which version to run project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you install RVM: https://rvm.io/

The install instruction is on the site.

After you're done installing RVM do.

`rvm install 2.5.3`

Then test with `ruby -v` to check if you have the version you want (2.5.3). If not we can help you from that point.

Comment: Thanks! Turns out all it needed was closing and opening Terminal again, but I will keep your answer in mind for future use :)